# How to convert string to dictionary by using python regex

Tags: python, regex

string format is like this `<000001|ABC=123|DEF=456|~GHI=TEST|JKL=O1234_ABC.pdf>`
output format should be like `{'ABC': '123', 'DEF': '456', '~GHI': 'TEST', 'JKL': 'O1234_ABC.pdf'}`

I wrote this: `groups = re.findall(r'(\w+)=(.*?)', line)`, but it failed to get last element.

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'([^|<>=]+)=([^|<>]*)', line)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, that you explicitly asked for a solution via regex, but please be aware that it is not necessary to employ regex in your simple case.

If you have to parse a lot of strings similar to your example you can get a much better performance in avoiding regex and just using the python built-in `split()` function for strings.

```
import re
from timeit import timeit

# Your example string
s = r"<000001|ABC=123|DEF=456|~GHI=TEST|JKL=O1234_ABC.pdf>"

# Using regex
a = re.findall(r'([^<=|>]+)=([^<|>]+)', s)
print("regex:   ", dict(a))

# Using str.split()
b = map(lambda x: x.split('='), s.strip('<>').split('|')[1:])
print("split(): ", dict(b))

# Performance
t1 = timeit("re.findall(r'([^<=|>]+)=([^<|>]+)', s)", globals=globals(), number=1000000)
print("time for regex: {:3.2f} s".format(t1))

t2 = timeit("map(lambda x: x.split('='), s.strip('<>').split('|')[1:])", globals=globals(), number=1000000)
print("time for str.split(): {:3.2f} s".format(t2))
```

Result:

```
regex:    {'ABC': '123', 'DEF': '456', '~GHI': 'TEST', 'JKL': 'O1234_ABC.pdf'}
split():  {'ABC': '123', 'DEF': '456', '~GHI': 'TEST', 'JKL': 'O1234_ABC.pdf'}
time for regex: 4.15 s
time for str.split(): 0.88 s
```

Answer (score 1):

`\w` only matches letters, digits, and underscore, it doesn't match `~` or `.`.

You should use a pattern that matches anything except your delimiters: `<` at the beginning, `|` between items, `=` between name and value, and `>` at the end.

```
re.findall(r'([^<=|>]+)=([^<|>]+)', line)
```

Comment: thanks, this also works